# Monte Carlo, Non-polar optical phonon scattering?

Tags: phonons

I have a question on electron and non-polar optical phonon scattering in GaAs. Is it allowed to consider intravalley electron non-polar optical phonon scattering in L-valley of GaAs? I found in the literature, people only consider intervalley (L to L) electron non-polar optical phonon scattering in GaAS. I wonder if anyone can help me why this is the case? Why do not people consider intravalley non-polar optical phonon scattering in L-valleys of GaAs?

Answer (score 0):

GaAs is a polar material, so you would have polar optical phonon scattering. L to L intervalley scattering would be more relevant to Ge, a non polar material.